# QGIS 3.16 Rasterize doesn't show anything

Tags: qgis, rasterization

[image]

To give more info. The input layer is bus stop buffer dissolved which i buffered several stops in the district for 200 m and dissolved it to get those greenish polygons in the layer.
The output extent is the cip muara layer (in yellow, district shapefile layer). After running it i got the raster layer "rasterized" with... nothing shown on the layer. Did i get something wrong?

Comment: You use value 0 as a burn value, and you assign 0 also as a nodata value. So all that you burn is marked as nodata by the same. Burn with value128 and you should see something grey.

Comment: ohh, it works. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: @user30184 is there any reason why its 128 ?

Comment: Yes, but the reason is just that it is something else than 0. I selected 128 from the middle of the range 0-255 to be half-grey. For example full white 255 would look invisible on your screen if the background is white as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a logical mistake with the settings that you use.

- `-a_nodata 0` means that gdal_rasterize writes into the metadata of the output raster that pixels with value 0 should be interpreted to mean nodata.
- Using `-burn 0` means that the polygons are rasterized so that the pixels will get value 0.
- Those two together mean that you are converting your polygons into nodata.
- The fix is not to use the same value for nodata and burn.

Comment: Ohh i see, i get the general gist of it. But is there any way to decide which value is best used for the nodata and burn parameter?